# How to resolve the conflict two ajax request at a same time

Tags: javascript, ajax, servlets

I have one nominal.jsp page,which includes header.jsp.Here i am using Ajax for the first time, for the request in header.jsp,then for the second time Ajax request is called to the nominal.jsp,i am facing the conflict issue in the Ajax request. Because of this issue,my preferred drop-down list is not displayed. Sometimes when response is entered in the JavaScript, the drop-downs are displayed and if the response are not entered in the JavaScript, the drop-downs are not displayed. Tried my level best to resolve the issue, but could not resolve it. Please help me guys

thank u,

My header.jsp code:

```
<script>
headerDisplay();
function headerDisplay()
{   var url ='<%=request.getContextPath()%>/summary?operation=header';
    transactionRequest(url);    
}  
function transactionRequest(url)
{
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
         {              
            req = new XMLHttpRequest();                   
            req.onreadystatechange = transactionResponse;                   
                     try
                     { 
                               req.open("POST", url, true); //was get                   
                           }
                    catch(e) 
                     {
                        alert("Problem Communicating with Server\n"+e);
                     }                  
              req.send(null);
        }       

         else if (window.ActiveXObject) 
        { 
             // IE
            req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            if (req)
                { 

                    req.onreadystatechange = transactionResponse;  
                    req.open("POST", url, true);
                    req.send();
                }
        }  
}
function transactionResponse()
{         
      if (req.readyState == 4)  // Complete
       {
                 if (req.status == 200) // OK response

             {      var servletVal = req.responseText;      
                 var myObject = eval('(' + servletVal + ')');                      
                     var userId = myObject.userId;

}}}......

</script>


And,this is my nono.jsp code:


<%@include file="/pages/common/header.jsp"%>

<script>
function displayNominal()
{
    document.getElementById("ajaxLoading").style.display="block";
    var url ='<%=request.getContextPath()%>'+'/nominalList';
    postRequest(url);
}

function postRequest(url) {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.onreadystatechange = nominalSelect;
        try {
            req.open("POST", url, true); //was get                  
        } catch (e) {
            alert("Problem Communicating with Server\n" + e);
        }
        req.send(null);
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        // IE
        req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        if (req) {
            req.onreadystatechange = nominalSelect;
            req.open("POST", url, true);
            req.send();
        }
    }

}
function nominalSelect() {

    if (req.readyState == 4) // Complete
    {

        if (req.status == 200) // OK response
        {
            var servletVal = req.responseText;

            var myObject = eval('(' + servletVal + ')');
            var userId = myObject.userId;
            if (userId == null || userId == "") {
                window.location = '/accounts1/?status=session';
            }
}}..

</script>

<body class="bodystyle" onload="displayNominal()">
<% if("N".equals(roleDemoStatus))
                 {%>
<!-- /#demo Header -->
    <div style="top: 0px; display: block;" id="header" class="fixed">
        <div class="outer">
            <h1 class="blog-title" style="text-align:center;margin-top:10px;"><span style="font-weight: normal; color:#777777; font-size: 30px;">accounts<font color="#5DA915">1</font>.co</span> Demo Only - <a href="https://accounts1.co/accounts1/pages/userRegistration/signup1.jsp"><font color="red">Click Here</font></a> To Use For Free Forever</h1>
        </div><!-- .outer -->
        <div style="display: block;" class="shadow"></div>
    </div>
<!-- /#Demo Header -->
    <%}  %> 
</body>
```

Again thanks for advance.

Comment: @Ramesh: Apparently he is not? Otherwise the question would be tagged with it.

Comment: Do not make `req` a global variable!

Comment: Back when I did my Ajax myself, I would create several different variables for each type of request. Now I would answer: use JQuery to do you Ajax calls rather than doing it yourself and you won't have this problem.

Comment: hi bergi and developerwjk, thank you so much i have complete this issues,again very very thanks lot.

Answer (score 0):

Use a single callback and a `try/catch` block to enforce the request order:

```
function transactionResponse()
  {
  // Check whether this is the initial callback or a subsequent one
  if (!!transactionResponse.state)
    {        
      try
        {
        //POST data from the GET request
        }
      catch(e)
        {
        //Get data from the GET request
        }
      }

  // Set state after the initial callback reference
  else
    {
    transactionResponse.state = this;
    }        
  }
```

**References**

- [Long Polling Experiment](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1976-long-polling-experiment-with-jquery-and-coldfusion.htm)